# Group the items in ng-repeat using the updated date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display the items like:

```
date:14 march 2016
 2042
 2000
date:15 march 2016
 1500
 1501
 1600
```

My code is:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in oc.mileage_data | groupBy: 'updated_at' ">
    <div class="div_day" >
        <p>{{key * 1000 | date: 'd MMMM y' }}</p>
    </div>
    <ion-list can-swipe="listCanSwipe">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="mileage in value" class="" style="padding: 0px;">
            <div class="listing_div">
                <i class="icon-mileage milage_color"></i>
                <h2>{{mileage.mileage}}</h2>
                <span></span>

            </div>
            <ion-option-button class="button-positive button_delete" ng-click="share(item)">
                <i class="ion-ios-trash"></i> Delete
            </ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

Please Help me to solve this. I want to display the items grouped by updated 
 date.
 I am getting the results like this:

```
date:14 march 2016
2042
date:14 march 2016
2000
date:15 march 2016
1500
date:15 march 2016
1501
date:15 march 2016
1600
```

Comment: Is the `key` in ng-repeat same as the `updated_at` property?

Comment: key contains the same value as 'updated_at'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json data:

```
var data = [
  {
    date: '14 march 2016',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    date: '14 march 2016',
    value: 2
  },{
    date: '15 march 2016',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    date: '15 march 2016',
    value: 4
  }
  ];
```

Group by date:

```
$scope.uniq = [];
angular.forEach(data,function(val,index) {
  if(angular.isUndefined($scope.uniq[val['date']])){
     $scope.uniq[val['date']] = [val['value']];
  }else{
     $scope.uniq[val['date']].push(val['value']);
  } 
});
```

//output:

```
['14 March 2016' : [1,2]........
```

Comment: Now, If the date field contains the timestamp date then what will be the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple ng-repeat and show them only if data match with ng-if like this:

```
//here only 2014
<div ng-repeat="item in data | groupBy: 'datetime' ">
<span ng-if="item.datetime.indexOf(2014) > -1">{{item.datetime }}</span>
</div>


//here only 2015
    <div ng-repeat="item in data | groupBy: 'datetime' ">
    <span ng-if="item.datetime.indexOf(2015) > -1"> {{item.datetime}}</span>
    </div>
```

//etc...

Comment: @KhushbooMahajan just adapt this code it will work, i am not going to write your code i am just giving you the solution.